# Running at the speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light

I understand that as your velocity approaches the speed of light, the amount of energy required approaches infinity.

So, hypothetically, you are in a space craft travelling just 3mph below the speed of the light. If you attempted to run the direction the craft is travelling, would you not be able to move? Or is there some special relativistic effect that comes in to play?

Comment: Yes., that answers my question. That didn't turn up in potentially related questions. So it is time that slows down for the one who is running, to compensate of the apparent violation of the speed of light. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the reference frame of the space craft you are initially stationary, so running even at 3 mph (or more) will be no problem.